# How to get file from clicked item?

Tags: android, listitem, audiotrack

Hi i'm still trying to make my wavPlayer. My apps has listitem that contain wav file. When I click a file, it should be played but it didn't. I've tried some way on OnListItemClick() to make it work (I marked it with double slash), but it still error. Most of error are nullpointer. Anybody can help me?

here's my code and log cat

```
public class PlayercobaActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
    PlayAudio playTask;
    Button startRecordingButton, stopRecordingButton, startPlaybackButton,
            stopPlaybackButton;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    int frequency = 11025;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    //File item ;
    String item;

   // File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Datarekaman/recording5.wav");
    //Cursor acursor;
    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playercoba);

        startPlaybackButton = (Button) this .findViewById(R.id.StartPlaybackButton);
        stopPlaybackButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StopPlaybackButton);

        startPlaybackButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        stopPlaybackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        startPlaybackButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopPlaybackButton.setEnabled(false);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        String[] projection = null;
        String sortOrder = null; // unordered
        String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("wav");
        String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{ mimeType };
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection , selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, sortOrder );

        if(null != cursor)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);

            setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);


        }
    }

    //@Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);


        //String name = cursor.getString(cursor. getColumnIndex(MediaStore. MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        //item =(String) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //File item = new File(name);
        //item = new File();
        //item = (String) view.getTag();
        //item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        item = cursor.getString(cursor. getColumnIndex(MediaStore. MediaColumns.DATA));
        //playTask = new PlayAudio();
        //playTask.execute();
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startPlaybackButton) {
            play();
        } else if (v == stopPlaybackButton) {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        startPlaybackButton.setEnabled(false);
        playTask = new PlayAudio();
        playTask.execute();
        stopPlaybackButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void stopPlaying() {
        isPlaying = false;
        stopPlaybackButton.setEnabled(false);
        startPlaybackButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private class PlayAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            isPlaying = true;
            int bufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency,
                    channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
            short[] audiodata = new short[bufferSize/4];
            try {
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(
                        new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(item)));
                AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency,
                        channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                audioTrack.play();
                while (isPlaying && dis.available() > 0) {
                    int i = 0;
                    while (dis.available() > 0 && i < audiodata.length) {
                        audiodata[i] = dis.readShort();
                        i++;
                    }
                    audioTrack.write(audiodata, 0, audiodata.length);
                }
                dis.close();
                startPlaybackButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopPlaybackButton.setEnabled(true);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AudioTrack", "Playback Failed");
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            startPlaybackButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopPlaybackButton.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        public MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c) {
            super(context, layout, c,
                    new String[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME},
                    new int[] { R.id.displayname});
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
05-19 23:01:17.015  13752-13752/com.example.agita.playercoba E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.agita.playercoba.PlayercobaActivity.onListItemClick(PlayercobaActivity.java:93)
            at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1287)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3078)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4159)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4947)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are extending `CursorAdapter`, you can get the Cursor at position through the first  argument of `onListItemClick`

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
item = cursor.getString(cursor. getColumnIndex(MediaStore. MediaColumns.DATA));
Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help bro, my apps now can play the file :)